# Why is a browser extension more secure than a pure web-based application?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption

I love the idea of crypto.cat for sharing sensitive information.  Recently, i had to send my wife my social security number and i didn't want to use email/sms/IM/etc... I wanted to use crypto.cat, but she didn't want to install an extension on her work computer, so just ended up calling her.

I found myself wondering why an extension is even necessary.  Looking back through their blog, I found that they switched from a pure web-based application to a browser extension.  They claimed this improves security but they didn't explain why.

Looking through their github, the code appears to be all javascript so why not just skip the extension?  Im thining about forking Crypto.cat and re-implementing a pure web-based version, but I'd like to understand why this is a bad idea before i start.

**My ideas so far**

- Using an extension would make phishing more difficult

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security and belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I honestly think that is the only perk, I just read through their [Threat Model](https://github.com/cryptocat/cryptocat/wiki/Threat-Model) and that seems to be the only apparent perk. I also don't think browsers give any extra privileges to extensions but I could be wrong. Interesting post though.

Comment: @rosscowar The main issue is code injection. But when he first converted to the extension model, firefox didn't offer a secure randomness source for normal websites. So a proper CSPRNG API was certainly another advantage.

Comment: As for randomness, why not use the ol' wiggle your mouse trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps prevent code injection attacks by men-in-the-middle. If you go to the Crypto.cat website every time you want to use the service, your browser will download the application source code to execute. A MITM could use this opportunity to inject code, which undermines the whole security of the service. Even SSL wouldn't necessarily help much unless you pay very close attention to the certificate and the entire chain of trust, since a MITM could wedge in his own certificate.

Installing a browser extension under trusted conditions once mitigates these concerns, since then the whole code is already on your machine and nobody can inject anything.

Comment: Good point!  So a MITM attach could potentially inject a function that sends the private key to a 3rd party.  From there, they could listen in on any conversations.

Comment: I still think it would be nice to have a non-extension version (with a hefty disclaimer) for scenarios like i explained above.